# highchart - irregular time series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to plot irregular time series data onto high chart such as this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/.

```
var dataArray = [
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-07", Brand: "Toyota", Count: 3},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-02", Brand: "Ford", Count: 258},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-03", Brand: "Ford", Count: 239},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-04", Brand: "Ford", Count: 197},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-05", Brand: "Ford", Count: 187},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-06", Brand: "Ford", Count: 418},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-07", Brand: "Ford", Count: 344},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-03", Brand: "Mercedes", Count: 43},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-04", Brand: "Mercedes", Count: 220},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-03", Brand: "Chrysler", Count: 3},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-04", Brand: "Chrysler", Count: 3},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-06", Brand: "Chrysler", Count: 6},
{ErrorDate: "2017-09-07", Brand: "Chrysler", Count: 1}
];
```

I have my data in variable dataArray, and I've attempted to build out a series data based on each brand from the data coming in, however the challenge I am having is that I need to dynamically pass in the 'ErrorDate' along with each data point in the series so that it is plotted appropriately.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntt5oc21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepare your data before passing it to Highcharts. This doc page should be helpful: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Here is your processed data:

```
var seriesArr = [];
dataArray.forEach(function(point) {

  var newPoint = [point.ErrorDate, point.Count],
    seriesIndex = seriesArr.findIndex((series) => series.name === point.Brand);

  if (seriesIndex === -1) {
    seriesArr.push({
      name: point.Brand,
      data: [newPoint]
    });
   } else {
    seriesArr[seriesIndex].data.push(newPoint);
  }
});
```

Then you can use one of the methods from **METHODS AND PROPERTIES
For dynamically modifying the chart** API section: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

For example:

```
seriesArr.forEach(function(series) {
    chart.addSeries(series);
});
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/knhx3yvz/